# Trying to display a numbered grid, stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++, and to programming anything beyond getting a single line of input and printing it to the screen. (I'm working from Alex Allain's Jumping Into C++.) I'm trying to print out a simple 3x3 grid, with each square numbered (TicTacToe board.) But I'm stuck at 1 in an infinite loop. I'm sure the problem is incredibly simple and probably obvious to everyone reading this, but I just can't see it.

Here is my code, and thanks in advance for your help:

```
    int main()
    {
        for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            cout << "_____________\n";
            while ( i <= 3 )
            {
                cout << "| " << i <<" |";
            }
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "|---|---|---|\n";
            while ( i > 3 && i <= 6)
            {
                cout << "| " << i <<".|";
            }
            cout << "/n";
            cout << "|---|---|---|\n";
            while ( i > 6 && i <= 9)
            {
                cout << "| " << i <<".|";
            }
            cout << "|___|___|___|\n";
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have the outer loop

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
```

Then you have an inner loop

```
while ( i <= 3 )
```

However when you reach that inner loop the first time `i` will be `1`, and it will never change in the inner loop so the expression `i <= 3` will *always* be true, and so you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use if instead of while.  You are not incrementing anything in those loops.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it with inner for-loops?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        // print your stuff here
    }
    // new line comes here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

"while" is a looping construct, not *just* a branching instruction.  Change your "while" statements to "if" and you should be fine.